# color blob detection OpenCV-2.4.4-android-sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, sdk, android-camera

I have downloaded, unzipped and imported the samples in this openCV SDK. So far I get no compilation errors (just had to install android 3.0 with SDK manager,  API 9 I think), the I ran the generated color blob detection apk in my android device and all I see is a black screen. That happens for the face detection example as well, for both the generated apk in eclipse and the apks included with the openCV sdk zip. Any ideas on why this is happening? or how to fix it ?

Comment: sorry, thar was API 11

Comment: Which android device are you using and which version of Android OS is that device running?

Comment: Gingerbread (Android 2.3.5) on a Mototola Defy+, for some reason, changing the ROM to CM10 seemed to have fixed all my issues. All the samples seem to be working now, but still, I don't know why that fixed the problem.